# Equation of a line in space

Tags: geometry, 3d

How do we find out the equation of a line when a point is given through which it passes along with the equation of two skew lines that it intersects?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1. Write the equation of the plane which contains the given point $P$ and **line 1**
2. Find the intersection point $Q$ between the plane and **line 2**
3. Find **Line PQ** which intersects both **line 1** and **line 2**